# A number rebus!

Tags: rebus

What phrase does the following rebus represent?

`146S873A2F469074E12T410943Y25`

This is my first attempt at a rebus, so I'm wide open to suggestions for improvement!

Comment: I am not sure on how this could be called a rebus ...

Comment: @fffred: It is a rebus: It represents a common saying visually and requires lateral thinking. It could be called a typographical rebus.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It represents

> Safety in numbers

Because

> 146**S**873**A**2**F**469074**E**12**T**410943**Y**25
>  And here, the bold letters combined make the word "Safety"

Comment: This is correct, I will mark as such when I'm allowed to.